# Is it a good/neutral/bad practice to use $this as a file-level variable in PHP (e.g. functions spanning files)?

Tags: php

It's kinda hard to explain what I mean, I don't know how to name this pattern, so I'll explain with an example:

#### First.php:

```
<?php
    class MyClass
    {
        public $Meaning = 42;

        public function MyFun
        {
            include("Second.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

#### Second.php:

```
<div><?= $this->Meaning ?></div>
```

In the **Second.php** we rely on being included from a method in `MyClass`, and use the `$this` variable. Somehow this feels... unnatural to me. Maybe it's because of my C# background, but I strongly feel that **functions don't span files**. Classes might, but not functions (OTOH spanning classes is exactly what PHP does *not* allow).

So... am I being unreasonable in this, or is this really considered a bad practice? Or perhaps in view-logic (think MVC) this is even the standard approach?

Comment: I would say that this is ugly.  What would be the reason for doing this?

Comment: I've seen this being done by others, several times. Lately I've even seen it being done as the standard practice in a templating engine called "PHP Savant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a bad practice. It does look a little unusual, but there are advantages. The main one as I see it is that you can access any member functions of the view (they would presumably be some kind of helpers) and do it polymorphically.

I don't know if the polymorphic capability makes much sense (will there be a hierarchy of views?) -- but if it does, this is a good syntax to access it.

Plus, there's also the minor message that the code in `second.php` gives off: "*this* is the view". Which is nice.

Comment: OK. To tell the truth, I'm intending to do something similar (I will _have to_ call `include` from a function), and I couldn't decide whether to go with `$this` or `$View`. I guess I'll take `$this` after all.

Answer (score 2):

It makes your View not usable without the class ; but, except from that, I don't think doing that is *bad practice*.

As far as I know, that's precisely what's done by some Frameworks -- like Zend Framework, for example.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about that too, but I also immediately thought of a counter-argument: the view will anyway depend on some external variables, like `$Model` or something. Why should `$this` be any different?

Comment: You're right : anyway, you won't be able to use your View without anything else.